# creating an object in window.opener that persist when child window closes

Tags: javascript, dom

Accessing and creating objects in window.opener is straight forward.

```
window.opener.myObj = new Object();
window.opener.myObj.name = 'Tom';
alert(window.opener.myObj.name); // alerts('Tom')
```

However, when the current (child) window closes, the object myObj becomes invalid as the object actually resides in the current window and the window.opener only retains a reference to it.

How, from the child window, can we create an object IN the window.opener DOM, so that it persists when the child (current) window closes?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the current (child) window closes, the object myObj becomes invalid as the object actually resides in the current window and the window.opener only retains a reference to it.

Have you proven that? <s>I have to admit not having tried it.</s> I [don't see that result](http://jsbin.com/uzulom/2) on either Chrome or Firefox. The object sticks around even when the child window is closed. **Update**: Curiously, on IE9, the *object* persists but the property does not.

<s>But assuming it's true, you could try</s>

```
window.opener.myObj = new window.opener.Object();
```

...but I wouldn't really hold out any great hope of success. **Update**: And this doesn't only not help with IE9, it actually makes it worse.

---

Instead, I think I'd have to advocate calling back to the parent window to ask *it* to create the object.

Parent window script:

```
function createFoo(spec) {
    window.foo = jQuery.extend({}, spec);
    display("Created <code>foo</code> as requested by child window");
}

jQuery(function($) {
    var childid = "childwin" + new Date().getTime();

    $("#openPopup").click(function() {
        var wnd = window.open("http://jsbin.com/asocuy/1", childid);
    });
    $("#displayFoo").click(function() {
        if (window.foo) {
            display("<code>foo</code> exists");
            display("<code>foo.name</code> = " + window.foo.name);
        }
    });
});

function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Child window script:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    if (window.opener) {
        if (!window.opener.createFoo) {
            display("<code>window.opener.createFoo</code> not found");
        }
        else {
            window.opener.createFoo({
                name: "Fred"
            });
            display("Asked parent window to create <code>foo</code> with name = 'Fred'");
        }
    }
    else {
        display("<code>window.opener</code> not found");
    }

    $("#btnClose").click(function() {
        window.close();
    });

    function display(msg) {
        $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
    }
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/usazon/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/usazon/1/edit) (even works in IE)

Comment: I have 'proven' it to my satisfaction and witnessed errors:
The callee (server) is not available and disappeared.

Comment: @user1806949: Any idea what's different about your example than mine, then? I don't see any problem with the object going away.

Comment: Humm - I am not sure I can answer. The code you provided above does not function. I get an error.
Error: invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: BTW - this is IE7 unfortunately

Comment: OK - I will try in FF and will try and find an IE8 - Employer very restrictive.

Comment: OK - thanks I looked at your code in FF and as you say it provides the desired result. Unfortunately the button to open a popup does not work in IE7. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: I can confirm that this technique does not work in IE7,IE8 or IE9. I knocked up a simple test to confirm. The same test works fine in FF and Chrome.

Comment: @user1806949: The reason the popups didn't work in IE was that I was giving them invalid names. But the original script didn't work in IE even when that was fixed; the updated script in the answer works even in IE. It has the child window asking the parent to create the object rather than creating the object directly.

Comment: Thanks again for the input. As I don't have control of the parent window except to have it open a URL which I have specified, I will have to come up with a way to add the code to the parent (a vendor provided portal). I will try a window.opener.document.write('<script...') and see what happens.

Comment: @user1806949: Don't use `window.opener.document.write`, it'll completely wipe out the contents of the parent window. Use `window.opener.document.createElement('script')` and then set the `src` of that script element. That will inject the script into the parent window. Obviously, you then have to use a `setTimeout` and poll the `opener` for some global symbol so you know the script has been downloaded and processed. But beware that basically none of this will work cross-origin because of the SOP (I say this b/c it's odd if you don't have control over the parent window but it's the same origin).

Comment: Interesting point on the document.write. I have used it before in a library loader routine (as in $require()), but I will take it under advisement. Thankfully the Portal and my page will be coming from the same JS domain so I should be ok on that score. Thanks.